# Youcompleteme function preview popup balloon in new version

Tags: python, vim

In the most recent version of YCM, I am getting this kind of popup balloons every time I open a function bracket in Python. I find it quite annoying and the automatic close mechanism often fails and leaves the popup on the screen.

Where is this coming from? I could not find anything from Vim logs about this popup, but did try to disable YCM and the popup disappeared.

I have tried to set

> set completeopt-=preview

but the issue persists.

How to disable this functionality?

[image]

Comment: Does `let g:ycm_disable_signature_help=1` line in .vimrc help?

Comment: No, same issue here. I alos tried with g:ycm_auto_hover = "" , let g:ycm_add_preview_to_completeopt = 0, set completeopt-=preview .
I can't get rid of that preview. Can't even close it with ;pc, I nned to move the cursor!

Comment: No, this did not solve the problem for me either!

Answer (score 6):

Add `let g:ycm_auto_hover=''` in your .vimrc file. Note that it will not work if you just type this in your vim command mode. It must be add into vimrc file and restart vim.

Comment: Also you can add a key map to toggle the pop-up preview: `nmap <leader>D <plug>(YCMHover)`

Comment: Neither of these helped. But I have investigated the problem more: If I quit the preview from insert mode with ctrl+c (which I often do), it will persist on screen even though it should not.

Comment: Strange， but it did work for me. Have you check that any other setting may overriding this configuration? I only have 2 set about ycm.

Comment: Works for me as well